# Complexity of Two sum III on LeetCode

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I am trying to working on the Two Sum III on LeetCode. Here is the question:

> Design and implement a TwoSum class. It should support the following
>   operations:add and find. add - Add the number to an internal data
>   structure. find - Find if there exists any pair of numbers which sum
>   is equal to the value. 
>   For example,  add(1); add(3); add(5);
>   find(4) -> true  find(7) -> false

I know two acceptable solutions, the first one uses a List and the second one uses a map. Here are the two solutions I have:

The List implementation:

```
public class TwoSum {
    private List<Integer> list;
    public TwoSum() {
        list = new ArrayList<Integer> ();
    }
    public void add(int num) {
        list.add(num);
    }
    public boolean find (int sum) {
        if(list.size() == 1)
            return list.get(0) == sum;
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if (list.contains(sum - list.get(i))) {
                if (list.indexOf(sum - list.get(i)) == i)
                    continue;
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

The Map implementation:

```
public class TwoSum2 {
    private Map<Integer, Integer> map;
    public TwoSum2() {
        map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    }
    public void add(int num) {
        if (!map.containsKey(num))
            map.put(num, 1);
        else 
            map.put(num, map.get(num) + 1);
    }
    public boolean find(int sum) {
        if(map.size() == 1)
            return map.containsKey(sum);
        for (int num : map.keySet()) {
            if (map.containsKey(sum - num)) {
                if (num == sum - num && map.get(num) == 1) 
                        continue;
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Two solutions should give me same complexity, O(1) for add and O(n) for find. However, the List implementation is slightly faster for several test cases I have. The only reason I can think of is it takes some time to get the hash code in the map and find the key. But I am not sure about this answer. What may be the possible reasons that the Map implementation is slower?

Thanks.

Comment: @Jason  Actually it is correct. The element is searched by its index, and if the found element (sum - list.get(i)) has the same index, the code will continue to search. E.g. add(3), list.get(0) = 3, list.indexOf(6 - 3) = 0, continue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For HashMap, there is variable called a load factor. If load factor is reached, the HashMap would reallocate more memory and rehash all key value pair. In this case the complexity is O(n) for a single put action, so it can possibly be slower.  Check out this [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

> An instance of HashMap has two parameters that affect its performance:
>   initial capacity and load factor. The capacity is the number of
>   buckets in the hash table, and the initial capacity is simply the
>   capacity at the time the hash table is created. The load factor is a
>   measure of how full the hash table is allowed to get before its
>   capacity is automatically increased. When the number of entries in the
>   hash table exceeds the product of the load factor and the current
>   capacity, the hash table is rehashed (that is, internal data
>   structures are rebuilt) so that the hash table has approximately twice
>   the number of buckets.
>
> As a general rule, the default load factor (.75) offers a good
>   tradeoff between time and space costs. Higher values decrease the
>   space overhead but increase the lookup cost (reflected in most of the
>   operations of the HashMap class, including get and put). The expected
>   number of entries in the map and its load factor should be taken into
>   account when setting its initial capacity, so as to minimize the
>   number of rehash operations. If the initial capacity is greater than
>   the maximum number of entries divided by the load factor, no rehash
>   operations will ever occur.